# Vertx: What do these errors mean?

Tags: amazon-ec2, java

I'm trying to run a java applet using the Vertx platform but getting the following errors, as I am not a java person.. I'm having a hard time understanding how to fix these, your help is much appreciated.

```
[root@ip-X mycompany]# vertx run Bidder.java 
Failed in deploying verticle 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:108)
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:51)
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$21.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1723)
        at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:175)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:370)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to detect java compiler, make sure you're using a JDK not a JRE!
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:84)
        ... 7 more

    Failed in deploying verticle 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:108)
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:51)
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$21.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1723)
        at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:175)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:370)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to detect java compiler, make sure you're using a JDK not a JRE!
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:84)
        ... 7 more
[root@ip-X mycompany]#
```

Edit:
JDK is already installed.

```
[root@ip-X mycompany]# rpm -qa |grep java
javapackages-tools-0.9.1-1.2.amzn1.noarch
tzdata-java-2013i-2.23.amzn1.noarch
**java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51-2.4.4.1.36.amzn1.x86_64**
[root@ip-X mycompany]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have installed the JDK but still getting error, there may be conflict between JDK and JRE classes.

Add path to bin folder inside jdk (like: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin) in the **CLASSPATH** system variable. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear. This piece of software expects a JDK (Java Development Kit) to be installed, not just a JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

Solution: Install a JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows.

When I added `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51` it worked for me

Comment: I sincerely doubt that works on Linux.

Comment: I had the same issue on Windows today. I managed to fixed it likewise. I forgot mentioned it's for Windows. I just hope it will help someone oneday